# Debugging Template code: What are some modern ways to do this on the command line?

Tags: c++, debugging, unix, command-line, gdb

Now this works, but it's pretty ugly, and not too friendly when you need to do it a whole lot.

```
(gdb) break diff_match_patch<std::__1::basic_string<wchar_t, std::__1::cha
r_traits<wchar_t>, std::__1::allocator<wchar_t> >, diff_match_patch_traits
<wchar_t> >::diff_linesToCharsMunge                                       
Breakpoint 4 at 0x100021a1c: file diff_match_patch.h, line 658.           
(gdb)
```

I am able to set breakpoints from the line number. This is likely what I will resort to most of the time, because:

To set a breakpoint with the name of a function, if it happens to be underneath a pile of templates (such as a class inheriting STL containers... grumble grumble), you have to go through this ordeal to  get the ungodly signature of it in order to break on a function.

Here's how I'm able to accomplish it, here on my OS X 10.8.4, you type `break` at the gdb prompt, then start going with the prefix (in this case it was diff_match_patch, the name of the class), then attempt to tab-complete. At this point I use tmux's search mode to isolate the signature of the function (`diff_linesToCharsMunge`) and you see what I have pasted there is the beginning portion of the function's signature, which is enough to get gdb to happily set a breakpoint on it.

Now I'd like to make this somewhat better, but I'm not sure how. I'd like to keep things clean and robust by staying on the command line.

I reckon that if I wanted a nice (and friendly) GUI interface a good way to go would be to set this code up in an XCode project and go from there.

But what sort of options are there for me if I want to take more of a core UNIX style approach?

gdb is solid, for sure (and boy am I glad it seems to work seamlessly with my clang-compiled C++11 code), but it's lacking many niceties like what we get from e.g. `ipython`. ipython has full blown *syntax highlighting*! The clang compiler produces nicely colored and super friendly (cf. `gcc` at least) errors and warnings. With the sweet squigglies to show you the parts of offending expressions! `gdb` is just feeling long in the tooth by comparison.

So I'm just trying to make this work a little less ... painful. The areas to improve...

1. have tab completion search from the middle of the function signature so I can just tab after typing the reasonable human-known name of the function
2. actually #1 about sums it up, but any viable workarounds that do other things (line number is one of them, i guess... sigh) are welcome. You know, I'm hoping maybe `clang` project has some epic feature rich gdb front-end.

Comment: b diff_match_patch.h:658

Comment: @JRG I know it does that, but I want it to be friendlier if I only know the function name!

Comment: break diff_match_patch<std::wstring, diff_match_patch_traits
<wchar_t>>::diff_linesToCharsMunge should work.

Comment: I think this particular `gdb` is pretty old-school, its copyright note says (c) 2004, and the version number is 6.3.50-20050815 (though apparently compiled on Nov 15 2012). So it's actually impressively useful for being so ancient. I reckon updating this to something brand spanking new might improve a thing or two.

Answer (score 0):

Oh right, I knew about this, but had forgotten it. Just stumbled across another answer that mentioned it:

http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html

Comment: This comes with OS X. Compiling it is a bit of an ordeal, but not too horrible. You'll need to compile it if you want to get LLDB for Linux. The upside there is that compiling from svn will give you a more up to date version than what OS X or Xcode will come packaged with.